# How can I get my current location ? [Android Google Map V2]

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

Here is my .Java file

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GoogleMap extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemap);

        // Get a handle to the Map Fragment
        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Sydney").snippet("The most populous city in Australia.").position(sydney));
    }
}
```

XML

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />



//GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

There is an error which is :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap to com.example.locdroid_v2.GoogleMap
```

Manifest File

My Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.locdroid_v2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>   

    <permission android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />



        <activity
            android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>



        <activity android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.GoogleMap"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>

        <meta-data 
             android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
             android:value="MyKey"/>

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@+integer/google_play_services_version" />

       </application>

</manifest>
```

As you all said i had

-Change Activity to FragmentActivity

-GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
 GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

because in your xml fiel you have used **SupportMapFragment** class.

Another thing is that extends your class as a **FragmentActivity** instead of **Activity**.

Remove these

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
 <activity android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.GoogleMap"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

Or change your Activity Name from GoogleMap to another and register as

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.locdroid_v2.MyGoogleMapActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

from your manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

As you have declared a class for the `SupportMapFragment` in your layout file so you have to use the class `SupportMapFragment` to cast your `GoogleMap` in your java file.

Try to load the map as below:

```
 GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: There are 2 errors which are : 
-The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type GoogleMap
And 
-Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap to com.example.locdroid_v2.GoogleMap

Comment: @user3424059 You will have to add the fragments support library `android-support-v4.jar` and google map library in your project's build path then only you will be able to get it.

Comment: pelu open gls ma seekbar wadu...online tha

Comment: I changed as you said and I already added android-support-v4.jar 
But i still have that error : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap to com.example.locdroid_v2.GoogleMap"

Comment: Change your Activity to `FragmentActivity`. @user3424059

Comment: Done but still the same problem

Comment: @user3424059 Try to clean your project.